# Wine settings to correct color palette?

Tags: wine, configuration, display, colors

I have a Windows application (Kidspiration 3 Starter), that when running under `wine 1.4` in Ubuntu 12.04 shows a completely distorted color palette that makes the interface unusable. See screenshot.

What is usually the way to correct this? Is there a particular `wine` library that I should switch to native?

Other details: wineHQ list Kidspiration 2.1 as "garbage", however version 3 installation and program works, except for the colors.

[image: kidspirationpalette]

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: @ArthurChamz  no, sorry.  But I didn’t see the problem again with newer Windows software.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess this is an issue with a program trying to run in 256-color mode.

The WINE wiki includes has [a page](http://wiki.winehq.org/256ColorMode) on running applications in 256 colors, but I'm afraid it isn't trivial:

It suggests you install the `Xephyr` nested X server:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr
```

Then create a 256 color window and run wine inside it:

```
Xephyr :1 -ac -screen 800x600x8 &
DISPLAY=:1 wine application.exe
```

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction but using this commands make the display even worst. I tried also with `800x600x16` and `800x600x32` and the result is the same as in the original post. I'll keep looking for a solution.